# Serilog sensitive data masking not applying when writing to application insights

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights, serilog

We have an application that logs requests to Application Insights via Serilog. As part of our GDPR compliance, we need to mask sensitive data and ensure it isn't written to the logs. We're using the `Serilog.Enrichers.Sensitive` package to achieve this.

I've created a custom `EmailMaskingOperator`, because we need to mask email addresses that could appear anywhere within a request URL and it needs to be slightly more forgiving than the default. I have tests that confirm the operator masks correctly. Here's the code for the `LoggerFactory` that wires up the masking operator:

```
public class LoggerFactory
{
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    public LoggerFactory()
    {
        var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile(path: "serilog.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile(path: $"serilog.{environment}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build();

        Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .Enrich.WithSensitiveDataMasking(
                options =>
                {
                    options.MaskingOperators = new List<IMaskingOperator>
                    {
                        new EmailMaskingOperator()
                    };
                    options.MaskValue = "***";
                })
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
            .CreateLogger();
    }
}
```

I've also tried configuring this via config (this is the `serilog.json`):

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Settings.Configuration", "Serilog.Expressions", "Serilog.Enrichers.Environment", "Serilog.Enrichers.Sensitive", "Serilog.Sinks.Console" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Override": {
        "System": "Warning",
        "Microsoft": "Information"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
        "Args": {
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Debug",
          "telemetryConverter": "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Debug"

        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ 
      "FromLogContext", 
      "WithMachineName", 
      "WithHttpRequestId",
      {
        "Name": "WithSensitiveDataMasking",
        "Args": {
          "options": {
            "MaskValue": "***",
            "Operators": [ "MyApplication.Logging.EmailMaskingOperator, MyApplication" ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The masking works fine when looking at debug or console output (example below), but fails to mask the email address when the same request is written to Application Insights. Am I missing something?

`"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:4567/api/people/lookup?user=*** - - - 200 109 application/json;+charset=utf-8 1844.5671ms","severityLevel":"Information","properties":{"MessageTemplate":"{HostingRequestFinishedLog:l}"`

Comment: Try this `Destructure.ByMaskingProperties("Password..` from [GitHub](https://github.com/evjenio/masking.serilog)

Comment: @Harshitha that library focuses on masking specific properties in types being logged. I need something that acts on the request URL itself as it goes through. I'm looking into creating a custom `RequestTelemetryConverter` at the moment